# Displaying Timeline from User Selection from Drop Down Menu?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

**EDIT >> This issue has been solved

This is my first post so hopefully it makes sense. :) I'm very new to R Shiny, but I have a project I'm working on and I've hit an obstacle that I can't seem to find solutions to online.

My goal for this app is that there will be two tabs. On the first, the user will be able to select different IDs from a drop-down menu and from there, a respective timeline will show up depending on which ID the user selected. The second tab will have the same idea, but will show two timelines instead of just one. (For now I'm only concerned about the first tab.)

I was able to input a drop box, but I can't figure out how to use timevis to create an output, nor can I figure out how I would have different timelines show up depending on the user's selection. My most recent attempt is below. I tried it with just one choice in the drop-down box to see if I could get the hang of it, but it produced no output at all.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(timevis)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  navbarPage("Timeline",
    tabPanel("Single Selection",
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("person", "Person:",
          c("123" = "p1")),
        ),
      mainPanel(
        timevisOutput("p1_tl")
      )
      ),
      tabPanel("Comparison",
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("person", "Person 1:",
            c("123" = "p1",
            "234" = "p2",
            "345" = "p3")),
          selectInput("person", "Person 2:",
            c("123" = "p1",
            "234" = "p2",
            "345" = "p3")),
      ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Under construction")
    )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p1_tl <- renderTimevis ({
    timevis(data = data.frame(
      start = c("2016", "2017", "2017", "2018"),
      end = c(NA, "2018", NA, "2019"),
      content = c("Item 1", "Item 2A", "Item 2B", "Item 3")，
      group = c(1, 2, 2, 3)),
      groups = data.frame(id = 1:3, content = c("G1", "G2", "G3"))
    ) %>%
  setGroups(data.frame(id = 1:3, content = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))
  })
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This doesn't answer the reactivity, but just to make your code work you are missing a key comma. In your ```renderTimevis```, after ```content = c("Item 1", "Item 2A", "Item 2B", "Item 3")``` you need a comma before that and group. If you add that then your code should run

Comment: @Silentdevildoll Thank you！